# Using the properties of the Matlab GUI components programatically

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I am trying to make a simple test. I want to see if the String property of an edit component has a certain value. How do I use this property programatically? A syntax like

```
if (edit.String=='Text') then...
```

Seems not to work. Where am I mistaking?

Comment: What's the error? What Matlab version are you using?

Comment: The dot notation for accessing handle properties [was introduced in R2014b](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/graphics-handles-are-now-objects-not-doubles.html) and is not a valid syntax in earlier versions. See [`get`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/get.html) and [`set`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html), as the answer below has said.

Comment: pre HG2: @excaza - true but you can make it valid syntax by wrapping it in `handle`   `edit = handle(edit); edit.String = 'ABC'`

Comment: @LuisMendo Matlab 2014a. About the error message, it's a bogus one, like Matlab always offers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `get` function

```
if(strcmp(get(obj, 'String'), 'Text')
```

If you don't know you object, you can use

```
findall(0, 'Tag', 'yourtag')
```

Comment: yes, it is typically a double number (0 is the root)